# Querying Records Based on Key & MAX Date Column

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am hoping I can get some clarification on how to best handle getting the data set correct and efficiently.

Here are three queries from three different tables I am working with. The Donor_ID is key between the tables, but as you can see - there are multiple records associated with each Donor_ID - with the runid_gmt column having differing dates.

Ideally, I would like use the max(runid_gmt) for each record - and join the EMAIL and ADDRESSES tables on the Donor_ID but only select the max(runid_gmt) record in each of those tables as well.

I believe that is what I need to do - but not sure. Any suggestions on how to tackle this problem?

`SELECT donor_id, last_name, birthdate, runid_gmt
FROM [dbo].TBL_DONORS where donor_id = '51999441' order by runid_gmt desc;`

[image: Donors]

`SELECT donor_id, city, state, zip, runid_gmt
FROM [dbo].TBL_ADDRESSES where donor_id = '51999441' order by runid_gmt desc;`

[image: Addresses]

`SELECT donor_id, donor_email, runid_gmt
  FROM [dbo].TBL_EMAIL where donor_id = '51999441' order by runid_gmt desc;`

[image: Email]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `row_number` window function:

```
select * from
(select *, row_number() over(partition by donorid order by gmt desc) rn 
 from donors) t1 join

(select *, row_number() over(partition by donorid order by gmt desc) rn 
 from addresses) t2 on t1.donorid = t2.donorid join

(select *, row_number() over(partition by donorid order by gmt desc) rn 
 from emails) t3 on t1.donorid = t3.donorid
where t1.rn = 1 and t2.rn = 1 and t3.rn = 1
```